# Zoom images in ScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, pinchzoom, zooming

I have a scroll view with some images in it, which i scroll horizontally. I want to zoom using pinch gestures. This is the code I'm using, but it isn't working. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions please?

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 140))) var frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
var subView = UIImageView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   getOfferImages()
   swipeGesture()
   setupView()
   scrollView.delegate = self
   scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
   scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
 }
 func configureScrollView(){

   scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
   scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
   scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
   scrollView.bouncesZoom = true

   pageNumberlabel.text = "1 of \(offersImagesArray.count)"
   self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

   for index in 0..<images.count {

       frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
       frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
       subView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
       subView.tag = 1
       subView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
       subView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       subView.sd_setImage(with: images[index], placeholderImage: UIImage(named:""), options: [.continueInBackground])
       self.scrollView.addSubview(subView)
   }
   self.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (self.scrollView.frame.size.width *  CGFloat(images.count)), height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)

 }
 func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
  // let image = self.view.findSubview(withTag: 1)
   return self.subView
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to added `PinchGestureRecognizer` to your storyboard then link it to a function like below.

```
@IBAction func scaleImage(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    self.subView.transform = self.subView.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
    sender.scale = 1
}
```

Note: `subView` should be replaced by the view you are attempting to scale.

Comment: So I tried this, it does recognise the pinch gesture, but it doesn't zoom the image, it just flickers a little.

Comment: @Stephanie Did that work for you? Or are you still having issues?

Comment: i wanted to scale the subView but the problem was that it only applied to last image inside the scrollView, just now I tried replacing it with the scrollView itself inside the function, it worked, even though it wasn't quite what i wanted it to look like. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Check out the other answer, this answer doesn't use the scroll view to zoom actually.

Answer (score 1):

1) set zoom scales

```
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
```

2) set up scroll view delegate, return your image in viewForZooming

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return myImageView
}
```